# I created Analysis services databases by xmla scripts. But I can't show the values in table. e.g. run DAX 'evaluate table_name',there presents nothing

Tags: sql-server, ssas, ssas-tabular, xmla

I want to create many Analysis Services Databases, but don't want to create Analysis Services Tabular Projects manually. So I run some xmla scripts. The databases are constructed After running, but I can't show or use the values in the table. when I run the DAX script 'evaluate table_name', there present nothing.

the example xmla scripts:

```
{
```

"create": {
    "database": {
      "name": "SQA_200_12",
      "compatibilityLevel": 1200,
      "model": {
        "culture": "en-US",
        "dataSources": [
          {
            "name": "SqlServer localhost SQATables",
            "connectionString": "Provider=SQLNCLI11;Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=SQATables;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=false",
            "impersonationMode": "impersonateAccount",
            "account": "fareast\v-yanze",
            "annotations": [
              {
                "name": "ConnectionEditUISource",
                "value": "SqlServer"
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "tables": [
          {
            "name": "200_12",
            "columns": [
              {
                "name": "Year",
                "dataType": "string",
                "sourceColumn": "Year",
                "sourceProviderType": "Char"
              },
              {
                "name": "Award",
                "dataType": "string",
                "sourceColumn": "Award",
                "sourceProviderType": "Char"
              },
              {
                "name": "Category",
                "dataType": "string",
                "sourceColumn": "Category",
                "sourceProviderType": "Char"
              },
              {
                "name": "Nominated work",
                "dataType": "string",
                "sourceColumn": "Nominated work",
                "sourceProviderType": "Char"
              },
              {
                "name": "Result",
                "dataType": "string",
                "sourceColumn": "Result",
                "sourceProviderType": "Char"
              }
            ],
            "partitions": [
              {
                "name": "200_12",
                "dataView": "full",
                "source": {
                  "query": " SELECT [dbo].[200_12].* FROM [dbo].[200_12] ",
                  "dataSource": "SqlServer localhost SQATables"
                }
              }
            ],
            "annotations": [
              {
                "name": "_TM_ExtProp_QueryDefinition",
                "value": " SELECT [dbo].[200_12].* FROM [dbo].[200_12] "
              },
              {
                "name": "_TM_ExtProp_DbTableName",
                "value": "200_12"
              },
              {
                "name": "_TM_ExtProp_DbSchemaName",
                "value": "dbo"
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "annotations": [
          {
            "name": "ClientCompatibilityLevel",
            "value": "400"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}

Or are there any different ways to create analysis services databases conveniently. Thank you.

Comment: Please rephrase your question as it is unclear as of now. Also, provide us with MCVE https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and don't just throw all your data at us. Also, be so nice and learn how to format the code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have not processed the model. Right click the name of the model database in SSMS, and select the Process option.